# IDE for Python: test a script

Tags: python, ide

Is there any IDE that allows to run a script in testing mode, allowing to replace at runtime, some values, like a folder or else?
I have a program that will have to run on a network i have no access to where I develop. Since it will use some specific folders to pick up files, I was wondering if i.e. I could use an IDE that using some parameters will translate all that is like \corporate\disk-c\myfolder into a c:\myfolder.

Thanks!

M

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=python+debugger

Comment: [pdb](http://docs.python.org/library/pdb.html)

Comment: sorry don't get why a debugger can help... clearly i can change a value while running in debug, but this is tedious... i'm looking, if exists, for a solution where i run in a test mode, where some values are automatically transformed based on some pre-setup...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In absence of some other file based config, you could just keep the variable definitions in a a file that you import in the main script (e.g, `config.py`), then have two different versions of that file for 'on' and 'off' network, (or ' development' and 'production', whatever) with the appropriate settings.  No IDE needed.